# Why is my tension map turning out as bumps?

Tags: node-editor, objects, normals, vertex-colors

I am having a problem with an tension map addon. https://blenderartists.org/t/revised-mesh-tension-add-on/1239091 <- that one. and the tutorial (by kext next) I was following is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVIYGNplslQ. I am pretty sure that I did all of the nodes correctly and yet my hot dog thing looks bumpy instead of creased [image: its bumpy instead of wrinkled]
with these nodes:
[image: same nodes as on video]

the tension map is showing as this:[image: green and red spots with red band around object]

is there any way to fix this??
Thanks